# setString doesn't support national characters in PreparedStatement(Oracle 12)

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, prepared-statement, oracle12c

We are using Oracle version 12.1.0.2.0 with `ojdbc7-1.0.jar` and JDK 8.

We use Hikari as connection pool if it's relevant and it's using `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

This is the [recommended driver](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) to use in oracle

> Oracle Database version      JDBC specification compliance
>
> 12.1 or 12cR1                 ojdbc7.jar with JDK 7 and JDK 8

In Spring application,we are using `PreparedStatement`, and we want to support national character as characters.

We use [setNString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNString(int,%20java.lang.String)) which works for new/updated queries

> Sets the designated paramter to the given String object. The driver converts this to a SQL NCHAR or NVARCHAR or LONGNVARCHAR value (depending on the argument's size relative to the driver's limits on NVARCHAR values) when it sends it to the database.

Can we add support (platform/config level) for **existing code** using `setString` without code change?

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(SQL_STATEMENT)) {
        ps.setString(1, THAI_TEXT);
}
```

Currently `setString` doesn't handle national characters (save as ?) although columns defined as `NVARCHAR2(50)`

Must we replace all `setString` with `setNString`?

or is there a flag/property/upgrade/fix that can add the national support using `setString`?

Comment: Which database and driver? Did you actually test it? I would expect most drivers to be able to handle this transparently assuming the columns are properly defined.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel We are using Oracle 12 with ojdbc7.jar. currently it works only with `setNString`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can issue occur when using driver `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` over `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`?

Comment: You should use `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`, but it should not make a difference. Also, ojdbc7.jar is not a version of the driver, it just specifies which Java version it targets (Java 7).

Answer (score 1):

You might get away with `oracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true`, see 19.2 in the [JDBC Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdbc/jdbc-developers-guide.pdf#unique_145) (however I find Oracle and the JDBC API highly confusing in this regard, it should work with setString)

Comment: Thanks for answering, actually we tried previously to add defaultNChar in connection level and it seems to effect performance (slower), can you comment on this?

Comment: @user7294900 i think we also have seen some overhead from charset conversion. bit its a good position to benin if you are not bottlenecked on db side ,)

Comment: Found comment in your link *If you set the value of defaultNChar to true and then access CHAR columns,
then the database will implicitly convert all CHAR data into NCHAR. This
conversion has a substantial performance impact.*